# Undefined is not an object (evaluating 'navigation.navigate') when trying to navigate between two sites React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I try to navigate between two pages in a React Native app. I keep getting errors for my implementations but I don't know why.

I have the following setup for a "Home" and "Settings" site in the React Native app with Navigator adjusted from the [documentation](https://reactnative.dev/docs/navigation):

**App.js**

```js
import Home from "./Home";
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';

export default function App() {
  return <NavigationContainer><Home/></NavigationContainer>
}
```

**Home.jsx**

```js
const Home = ({ navigation }) => {
  return (
    <View style={["some style...", {}]}>
      <View style={["some style..."]}>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() =>
        navigation.navigate('Settings')}>
          <Image "some image..."/>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    </View>
```

**Settings.jsx**

A component which should be rendered.

**MyStack.jsx**

```js
import * as React from 'react';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/native-stack';
import Home from './Home';
import Settings from './Settings';

const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();

const MyStack = () => {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator>
        <Stack.Screen
          name="Home"
          component={Home}
        />
        <Stack.Screen name="Settings" component={Settings} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
};
```

I get `undefined is not an object (evaluating 'navigation.navigate')`. Also adding `this.props` to `navigation.navigate('Settings')` throws and error. I am just not able to access my Navigator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be setting up a navigator but never using it, since in `App.js` you are just calling `<Home/>`.

1. Change `App.js` to this:

```js
import MyStack from "./MyStack"; // Use the correct path for the import

export default function App() {
  return <MyStack/>
}
```

2. Add at the end of `MyStack.jsx`:

```
export default MyStack;
```